# How to add a custom module from a Github repository to an Odoo.sh project?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo.sh

I have written and tested an Odoo module locally and pushed it to it's own Github repository. Now I want to add it to an Odoo.sh project.

I have tried creating the Odoo.sh project from the repository. Sure enough it adds the code from my repository with the following folder structure into the User directory: [image]

The problem is that I am not able to install the module. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error message when you install your module from the Applications ?

Comment: The module does not appear in the list of modules.

Comment: ...Have you removed the "Application" filter in the search bar ?

Comment: Yes I have removed the filter

Comment: Could you post the content of the LOG-Tab of the (Staging or Master? ) branch, right after having pushed your code via Github ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding the module files into another folder and add this folder to Github and then check. Probably Odoo.sh is not able to recognise the module since it is not having a structure.

Comment: I had not understood the folder structure correctly. I moved my module into it's own directory within the Github repository so that it now appears at user>mymodule and it now works correctly.